# Windows ipython notebook -how to do cd cs231n/datasets ./get_datasets.sh

Tags: windows, python-3.x, ipython

I am running windows 10 and anaconda python 3.6
I want to run this, where cs231n in a directory under my working directory

```
cd cs231n/datasets
./get_datasets.sh
```

File "", line 1
    cd cs231n/datasets
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also tried

```
cd cs231n\\datasets\\
.\\get_datasets.sh
```

[Error 267] The directory name is invalid: u'cs231n//datasets/.//get_datasets.sh'
C:\Users\Bill\Documents\assignment1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to run a shell script in Python. The IPython kernel [provides the `%cd` magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) to change directories, and [the `!` to run shell commands](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access).

So you should run something along the lines of:

```
%cd cs231n/datasets # IPython magic command to change directories
! ./get_datasets.sh # Shell command within IPython. 
print('Got datasets.') # Regular Python code.
```

If not sure about what is going on, check out [differences between Python and IPython.](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#python-vs-ipython)